# Serial port permission error, and 'unexpected keyword argument' related to 'Systole' package when plotting raw PPG time series

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I'm trying to assess if an Oximeter plugged in via USB is correctly collecting heart rate data. I am using the Systole package, and some pre-writtend code sourced here (Scroll down to Recording PPG Signal :[Recording PPG Signal code](https://embodied-computation-group.github.io/systole/auto_examples/Recording/plot_RecordingPPG.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-recording-plot-recordingppg-py)

I am having 2 errors, the first is:SerialException: could not open port 'COM4': PermissionError(13, 'Access is denied.', None, 5)

And the second is:TypeError: plot_raw() got an unexpected keyword argument 'show_heart_rate'

The script I am trying to run:

```
from systole.recording import Oximeter


#Option for usin a simulated device, which I am not doing

    from systole import serialSim

 # Use a USB device  
import serial
ser = serial.Serial("COM4")  # Use this line for USB recording
```

#Plotting

```
oxi = Oximeter(serial=ser).setup().read(duration=10)
oxi.plot_raw(show_heart_rate=True, figsize=(13, 8))
```

Below is my desired output:

[image: Desired output]

Comment: the error `'COM4': PermissionError(13, 'Access is denied.', None, 5)` means that the COM port is already taken by another program

Comment: Yes, I think that was the problem with the COM issue, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

like I said in a comment the error `'COM4': PermissionError(13, 'Access is denied.', None, 5)` means that the COM port is already taken by another program.

---

I think that the second error is because of this line:

```
oxi = Oximeter(serial=ser).setup().read(duration=10)
```

according to `systole` api documentation you are supposed to do:

```
# ................................
oxi = Oximeter(serial=ser)
oxi.setup()
oxi.read(duration=10)
# ................................
oxi.plot_raw(show_heart_rate=True, figsize=(13, 8))
```

---

[systole api documentation](https://embodied-computation-group.github.io/systole/generated/recording/systole.recording.Oximeter.html#systole.recording.Oximeter)

Comment: Appreciate the further suggestion. I tried running it in that form and I am still getting the same error:    oxi.plot_raw(show_heart_rate=True, figsize=(13, 8))
TypeError: plot_raw() got an unexpected keyword argument 'show_heart_rate'

Comment: did you tried without `show_heart_rate` keyword, I can't seem to find anything about this keyword in their docs are you sure this is right?

Comment: I have found the issue now. I had an old version of Sytole installed, and when updated this problem went away.

Answer (score 1):

I'm sorry but are you sure you are pointing to the right file? this generation of errors occurs when the file is not reached because it does not exist.

also in the service documentation to write or read a file you should do:

```
import serial

s = serial.Serial('COM7')
res = s.read()   # or s.write()
print(res)
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Reading this feedback I think maybe the port is in use by another program, perhaps that is casuing the error in the plot, as that is where the data is coming from.